# Wireless and Wired network interfaces Windows 7 route table

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, routing

I have my laptop connected to wifi for internet and Ethernet for private network. I want to be able to connect to both.

I know that my private network range is 10.x.x.x  so I added a route rule to the table

```
route add  10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.56.12.1  metric 3
```

and here is the rout print output

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 22...80 19 34 ee e8 f0 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260 #3
 18...00 11 22 33 44 55 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I218-LM
 27...02 b0 22 12 08 01 ......BlackBerry Virtual Private Network
 24...82 19 34 ee e8 f1 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2
 23...82 19 34 ee e8 f0 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 21...80 19 34 ee e8 f4 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #3
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 28...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 30...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 34...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.56.12.1     10.56.12.194     50
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.27.0.1    172.27.41.169     40
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       10.56.12.1     10.56.12.194     53
       10.56.12.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.56.12.194    276
     10.56.12.194  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.56.12.194    276
     10.56.12.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.56.12.194    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      169.254.0.97    261
     169.254.0.97  255.255.255.255         On-link      169.254.0.97    261
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      169.254.0.97    261
       172.27.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     172.27.41.169    276
    172.27.41.169  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.27.41.169    276
   172.27.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.27.41.169    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.56.12.194    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      169.254.0.97    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.27.41.169    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.56.12.194    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      169.254.0.97   9999
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.27.41.169    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       1
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       1
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       1
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       1
          0.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       10.56.12.1       3
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 27    261 fd00::/8                 On-link
 27    261 fd2c:238f:e5ae:8322:7d91:6a3:7dd7:6894/128
                                    On-link
 18    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 27    261 fe80::/64                On-link
 22    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    286 fe80::585d:cce3:fbac:ab6d/128
                                    On-link
 27    261 fe80::91df:d8be:fada:61/128
                                    On-link
 22    281 fe80::c180:3e55:cd90:ac32/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
 27    261 ff00::/8                 On-link
 22    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

The problem is that this setup allows private network access only with no internet access. I used wireshark and I noticed that DNS quires are going through NIC with no answers in the reply

Chrome is using 8.8.8.8 for DNS quires which is routed to wifi and the answer is returned but still pages are not displayed.

How can I support both network interfaces to work together.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working. It turned out that I had to be more specific with the routes going to my Ethernet interface.

So, I had to define a **route** for each IP **subnet**

for example:

```
route add 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0
route add 10.36.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

and also to **remove** the **default** route:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0  255.0.0.0       10.56.12.1
```