# use wireless and cable connection at the same time for separate applications

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

In Windows O.S. I am connected with both wired and wireless connection. I would like to connect application A with wireless and application B with the wired connection. Is it possible?

Why I need this? well, I am using a VPN connection that forces me to disconnect the internet. I want it only limited to the wireless connection and use the cable connection with the browser.

Comment: Hi. I have the impression that you want a (as in any) solution to continue browsing the Internet while simultaniously connected to a VPN. Is that correct? Because that likely will generate more and different anwers than a 'I want to get this specific thing working, and ignore any all answers even if they are much easier'.

Comment: Yes you are right. feel free to modify the question

Comment: @Woeitg It's your responsibly to [edit] and clarify the question.

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like this?https://superuser.com/questions/1018377/wireless-and-wired-network-interfaces-windows-7-route-table

Comment: For me, the question is fine like this.